# Module not found error when trying to use shell_plus of django-extensions

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

I am trying to use the shell_plus that populates your shell with all your models. I put into INSTALLED_APPS: django_extensions. As soon as I try to run `python manage.py shell_plus` I get

```
$ python manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django_extensions\admin\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from django_extensions.admin.widgets import ForeignKeySearchInput
  File "C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django_extensions\admin\widgets.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static import static
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static'
```

If I am to comment out django_extensions and run `python manage.py shell` the shell works and defaults to ipython.

```
Cody@DESKTOP-HSSDN5O MINGW64 ~/Desktop/drf_tutorial
$ pip freeze
...
Django==3.0.6
django-extensions==2.2.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
...
```

settings.py

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'django_extensions',
    'snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'drf_tutorial.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'drf_tutorial.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Update django-extensions to 2.2.9 version, maybe 2.2.1 is not compatible with Django 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution could be the path to your static.py :)

Answer (score 0):

That problem was [fixed](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/pull/1428) in a recent version of Django Extensions. Latest version is 2.2.9, and you're using 2.2.1.